# How to define this regex with alternation to have the same number of groups in the match?

Tags: regex, parsing, conditional-statements, alternation

I am trying to parse such strings

```
99_GOG_A_X1_FOO X-2014-09
99_YAK_A_YZ1_BAR YZY-2014-10
```

with this regex

```
99_\w{3}_(A|B)_((X)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)_(FOO|BAR) X-(\b0*20(1[4-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b)-\b0*([1-9]|1[0-2])\b|(YZ)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)_(FOO|BAR) YZY-(\b0*20(1[4-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b)-\b0*([4]|1[0])\b)
```

The first input can only have 1 to 12 at the end while the second input can only have 04 or 10.
This works. but i would like to have a solution which only returns matching groups.

With this solution I have these groups http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiwuuALDA/index.html

I have superfluous groups and the matching groups are not on the same indexes for both inputs.

Is there a way to get rid of the empty groups and to align the indexes?

Update:
I have to keep the following rules.
If the input matches this `_((X)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)` it must also contain `X-` and allow this range at the end `\b0*([4]|1[0])\b`

If the input matches this `_(YZ)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)` it must also contain `YZY-` and allow only this inputs at the end `\b0*([4]|1[0])\b`

So I want to combine these regex:

```
^99_\w{3}_(A|B)_(X)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)_(FOO|BAR) X-(\b0*20(1[4-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b)-\b0*([1-9]|1[0-2])\b$
^99_\w{3}_(A|B)_(YZ)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)_(FOO|BAR) YZY-(\b0*20(1[4-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b)-\b0*([4]|1[0])\b$
```

Comment: Instead of making such a long winded regex, you should try splitting on underscores, spaces, and dashes. That will be much more readable and easier to change if necessary.

Comment: However, if you're stuck with regex, [check out the demo](http://regex101.com/r/xA9lC1/1). I tried to maintain your indexing as best I could.

Comment: I have updated the question with the required rules

Comment: You should post a string that has similar format, but shouldn't match the regex. That will be easier to work with than reading the rules (although rules are always good for regex).

Comment: I have added both regex i want to combine

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this could work for you:

```
99_\w{3}_(A|B)_((X|(?>YZ))(0*[1-9][0-9]?)_(FOO|BAR) \3Y?-(\b0?20(1[4-9]|[2-9][0-9])\b)-\b0?((?:[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:[4]|1[0]))\b$)
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xA9lC1/4)**

If this fails (which it might) you should consider use actual code to make sure it passes "*`((X)(0*[1-9][0-9]?)` it must also contain `X-` and allow this range at the end `\b0*([4]|1[0])\b`*"

Use the capture groups to check if `\3 == 'X'` or if `\3 == 'YZ'` and then apply the rest of the regex as necessary

Comment: Does not work. This allows these inputs:
``99_YAK_A_X1_BAR YZY-2014-10``
``99_GOG_A_YZ1_FOO X-2014-10``

Comment: I guess i will settle on two regex expressions with which i will test the input. So an input either matches the first, the second or no regex.

Comment: No, does not work, fails on this: ``99_GOG_A_X1_FOO X-2014-11``

Comment: @mrt181 Perhaps [this one](http://regex101.com/r/xA9lC1/4)? If this doesn't work you should definitely consider using real logic statement instead relying solely on regex. Good luck!

Comment: the last one looks good :) I will investigate the constructs you used and increase the sample inputs.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show this latest update of the regex. Accept it only if it helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59617/discussion-between-mrt181-and-skamazin).